# iOS App Crashes in release mode "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.propTypes.children')"

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, react-native-ios

Crashes only in release mode. Then, in Schema setting, for release mode, I enabled the "debug executable" and ran and got the following error. I have no clue where this error is coming from. There is no stacktrace. How do I proceed further? Please help me.

> [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] undefined is not an object
>   (evaluating 'e.propTypes.children')

Full System log below

```
Jun 10 10:03:03 My-MacBook-Pro assertiond[2748]: Submitted job with label: UIKitApplication:com.testdomian.testapp[0x894c][2748]
Jun 10 10:03:03 My-MacBook-Pro SpringBoard[2743]: [com.testdomian.testapp] Bootstrap complete with label: UIKitApplication:com.testdomian.testapp[0x894c][2748]
Jun 10 10:03:03 My-MacBook-Pro watchlistd[2807]: Now playing app did change to '(null)' (playing: 0) from '(null)'
Jun 10 10:03:03 My-MacBook-Pro watchlistd[2807]: WLKPlaybackSummary - Parameter failed validation bundleID. It is nil
Jun 10 10:03:03 My-MacBook-Pro testapp[5211]: assertion failed: 16F73 14E269: libxpc.dylib + 64131 [624BAF4F-2E03-34F8-ACBA-970B04637786]: 0x7d
Jun 10 10:03:03 My-MacBook-Pro testapp[5211]: Falling back to loading access token from NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug
Jun 10 10:03:03 My-MacBook-Pro testapp[5211]: Falling back to storing access token in NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug
Jun 10 10:03:03 My-MacBook-Pro testapp[5211]: Falling back to loading access token from NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug
Jun 10 10:03:03 My-MacBook-Pro testapp[5211]: Falling back to storing access token in NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug
Jun 10 10:03:03 My-MacBook-Pro testapp[5211]: Falling back to loading access token from NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug
Jun 10 10:03:03 My-MacBook-Pro testapp[5211]: Falling back to storing access token in NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug
Jun 10 10:03:03 My-MacBook-Pro assertiond[2748]: client <BSProcessHandle: 0x7fa250c05f10; testapp:5211; valid: YES> HWM increased to 1 because of <BKProcessAssertion: 0x7fa250c0b380; "FIRClearcutLogger.sendLogs" (finishTask:180s); id:…6CB5E848CE25>
Jun 10 10:03:03 My-MacBook-Pro testapp[5211]: [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.3700000 started
Jun 10 10:03:03 My-MacBook-Pro testapp[5211]: [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled ()
Jun 10 10:03:03 My-MacBook-Pro testapp[5211]: *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is NULL
Jun 10 10:03:03 My-MacBook-Pro testapp[5211]: [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS003007] Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
Jun 10 10:03:03 My-MacBook-Pro testapp[5211]: [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS005000] The AdSupport Framework is not currently linked. Some features will not function properly. 
Jun 10 10:03:03 My-MacBook-Pro testapp[5211]: [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Firebase Analytics enabled
Jun 10 10:03:04 My-MacBook-Pro pasted[2756]: BundleID com.testdomian.testapp from team F9477J636M is requesting pasteboard fb_app_attribution
Jun 10 10:03:04 My-MacBook-Pro pasted[2756]: ...requesting pasteboard fb_app_attribution completed. Error: (null)
Jun 10 10:03:04 My-MacBook-Pro testapp[5211]: Normal message received by listener connection. Ignoring.
Jun 10 10:03:04 My-MacBook-Pro testapp[5211]: Could not successfully update network info during initialization.
Jun 10 10:03:04 My-MacBook-Pro testapp[5211]: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.propTypes.children')
Jun 10 10:03:04 My-MacBook-Pro testapp[5211]: Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.propTypes.children')
Jun 10 10:03:04 My-MacBook-Pro testapp[5211]: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
Jun 10 10:03:04 My-MacBook-Pro testapp[5211]: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.propTypes.children')', reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.propTypes..., stack:
    p@642:1226
    <unknown>@642:1289
    o@2:553
    <unknown>@482:671
    o@2:553
    <unknown>@430:226
    o@2:553
    <unknown>@429:79
    o@2:553
    <unknown>@428:79
    o@2:553
    <unknown>@43:176
    o@2:553
    <unknown>@13:72
    o@2:553
    <unknown>@12:30
    o@2:553
    i@2:266
    global code@1271:9
    '
    *** First throw call stack:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010494cb0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000103802141 objc_exception_throw + 48
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001049b5625 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
        3   testapp                            0x0000000102902670 RCTFatal + 393
        4   testapp                            0x00000001028fbb7d -[RCTExceptionsManager reportFatalException:stack:exceptionId:] + 507
        5   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001048d4c6c __invoking___ + 140
        6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001048d4b40 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 320
        7   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001048ec956 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 54
        8   testapp                            0x00000001028ff6ab -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 551
        9   testapp                            0x0000000102926985 -[RCTBatchedBridge callNativeModule:method:params:] + 229
        10  testapp                            0x0000000102926223 __33-[RCTBatchedBridge handleBuffer:]_block_invoke.352 + 509
        11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106c3e585 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
        12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106c5f792 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
        13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106c45237 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 1022
        14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106c4598f _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1053
        15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106c45d31 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 374
        16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106c47899 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 813
        17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106c4750d _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 113
        18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010890a5a2 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
        19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010890a07d start_wqthread + 13
    )
Jun 10 10:03:04 My-MacBook-Pro SpringBoard[2743]: [KeyboardArbiter] HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
Jun 10 10:03:04 My-MacBook-Pro SpringBoard[2743]: UNSUserNotificationServerConnectionListener connection invalidated
Jun 10 10:03:04 My-MacBook-Pro com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.C3124FEB-FBFB-4DF6-9906-6E7CEF350078.launchd_sim[2726] (UIKitApplication:com.testdomian.testapp[0x894c][2748][5211]): Service exited due to Abort trap: 6
Jun 10 10:03:04 My-MacBook-Pro backboardd[2744]: [Common] Unable to get short BSD proc info for 5211: No such process
Jun 10 10:03:04 My-MacBook-Pro backboardd[2744]: [Common] Unable to get proc info for 5211: Undefined error: 0
Jun 10 10:03:04 My-MacBook-Pro assertiond[2748]: Deleted job with label: UIKitApplication:com.testdomian.testapp[0x894c][2748]
Jun 10 10:03:04 My-MacBook-Pro watchlistd[2807]: Now playing app did change to '(null)' (playing: 0) from '(null)'
Jun 10 10:03:04 My-MacBook-Pro watchlistd[2807]: WLKPlaybackSummary - Parameter failed validation bundleID. It is nil
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the issue. One of the third-party components was causing it because I as passing null to somehow.

Comment: @ChathuraPalihakkara Thanks

Comment: how did you proceded to find the specific location?

Answer (score 0):

Check what is the different in your schemas Debug Vs Release. 
Ex: Optimization Level in build settings.

Comment: It was set to faster, but even after I changed to None (same as debug), it crashes in the release. Works fine in debug mode